# Azure Functions - Concurrency Issue

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-functions

I'm planning a project and working through all the potential issues I might face. One that I keep running into which might be specific to my project is concurrency issues. From my understanding, Azure Functions scale when under demand which is exactly what I'm looking for but causes a problem when it comes to concurrency. Let me explain the scenario:

1. Http triggered Azure Function which does the below
2. Gets clients available credit, if zero, auto-charge clients card.
3. Deduct credit from the client for the request.
4. Processes the request and returns to the client.

Where I see an issue is getting the available credit and auto-charging card. Due to the possibility of having multiple instances of the function I might auto-charge the card multiple times and on top of that getting and deducting the credit will be affected.

I'm wanting the scaling of Azure Functions but can't figure a way around these concurrency issues. Any insight or pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What you're describing is not specific to Azure functions, it's a general issue you have to deal with in your architecture. You will need to consider your tolerance for eventual consistency and how you can resolve double charging a card, etc. The alternative is some kind of resource locking (i.e. pessimistic concurrency) which could adversely affect the scalability.

Comment: Yip, it's not an issue specific to Azure functions but due to the nature of there scalability, it's thrown me off. Yes, locking resources would adversely affect scalability but let me take a look into that. Thanks, Matt

Comment: @Sethles Please see if you can leverage Sessions in Service Bus. May be you can create a service bus queue in between. You can use Sessions to sequence the messages.

Comment: Yes, Azure functions auto-scale.  Yes concurrency can be an issue, but not without an event to cause it. HttpTrigger functions are event driven.  In your system,  what triggers the event?  How possible to have two or more events on one client in rapid succession? Any way to prevent that?  Most website cart checkout screens have this after pressing submit, "Please don't press the refresh or resubmit button".  Is it possible to prevent multies events on the same client in rapid succession?